# Asset files not found when publishing npm package and running with NPX

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

I'm trying to make a "Business Card" using node that automatically runs with NPX.

I want after running `npx my_package_name`, a display using chalk to show, then a input feedback loop that displays some pictures. I have everything working locally, however after publishing and running `npx my_package_name` on a different directory, I get `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory` in different lines when trying to open files I have in the project.

My package directory looks like this

```
|-index.js  
|-package.json  
|-package-lock.json  
|-text.txt  
|-assets/image1.jpg  
|-assets/sound1.mp3
```

my package.json looks like this

```
{
  "name": "my_package_name",
  "version": "1.1.2",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "bin": "./index.js",
  "files": [
    "index.js",
    "text.txt",
    "assets/sound1.mp3",
    "assets/image1.jpg"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "my github url"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "setup": "ncu -u && npm i",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "boxen": "^7.1.0",
    "chalk": "^5.2.0",
    "clear": "^0.1.0",
    "enquirer": "^2.3.6",
    "got": "^13.0.0",
    "inquirer": "^9.2.7",
    "open": "^9.1.0",
    "play-sound": "^1.1.5",
    "speaker": "^0.5.4",
    "terminal-image": "^2.0.0",
    "terminal-kit": "^3.0.0",
    "username": "^6.0.0"
  }
}
```

The asset files in my index.js code are referenced like this:

```
const __dirname = path.resolve();
let catPhotoPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/image1.jpg');
```

previously there were just referenced using a relative path aka `"./assets/image1.jpg"`

I can't find anyway on how to ensure that the asset files will be findable by the node.js package when being ran by `npx package_name`